# Сбрасывается cookie

Tags: php, cookie

```
if($_GET['test'] == 1) {
 setCookie('user_hash', 123, time() + 86400, '/');
}
echo $_COOKIE['user_hash'];
```

Это конечно странно, но данная кука хватает на 5-6 минут и потом удаляется. Как такое может быть?

Comment: Браузер быть может?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так, не указывай в конце этот параметр "/"

```
  $val="123";
    if (setcookie ("user_hash", $val,time()+86400);) echo "<h3>Печенюшки испеклись!</h3>";
else echo "<h3>Печенюшки, не испеклись :(!</h3>";
```

Ну и если у куки срок жизни сутки, то пока ты не почистишь кэш кук или не пройдут сутки, кука останется у тебя.

Comment: @Shrek, Пробывал так, всё равно сбрасывается... Держится лишь 5 минут.

Comment: Да не может быть такого, значит проблемы в браузере. Какой браузер юзаешь? открой в мозиле открой настройки страницы и посмотри куки на ней.

обновил ответ.